# div with php code not hiding by javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have three tabs. On click each tab shows certain info. But when I click edit the required form is not coming. Only when I click profile tab its working.If I delete the php code and put simply html code in profile div the tab works. I mean if i click profile it works and hide edit div and vice versa. But not with php code in it. I want edit tab to work with php code in profile tab. How can I solve this?

```
<div class="tabmember">
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="opentab1(event, 'profile')">Profile</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="opentab2(event, 'edit')">Edit</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="opentab(event, 'myorder')">My Order</button>
  <button class="tablinks" onclick="opentab(event, 'logout')">Log out</button>
</div>

<div id="profile">
<?php

  $email=filter_var($_SESSION['email'],FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL) ;

  $user_query="select * from user where email='$email'"; 

    $run_query=mysqli_query($dbcon,$user_query);  

    if(mysqli_num_rows($run_query)>0)  
    {  

      echo' <table border="2">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>id</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>status</th>
            <th>zip</th>
            <th>name</th>
            <th>password</th>
            <th>address</th>
            <th>country</th>
            <th>expires</th>

          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>';


      while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $run_query)){
        echo "<tr><td>{$row['id']}</td><td>{$row['email']}</td><td>{$row['status']}</td><td>{$row['zip']}</td><td>{$row['name']}</td><td>{$row['password']}</td><td>{$row['address']}</td><td>{$row['country']}</td><td>{$row['expires']}</td></tr>\n";
      }

    }
    else {
      echo"<script>alert('error retrieving from database! Contact admin!')</script>"; 
    }

    //close con
    mysqli_close($dbcon);

?>

</div>

<div id="edit">
  <form id="actform" action="new_user.php">
    <div><a href="bbc.com">AAA</div>        
    <input type="text" id="email" name="email_" placeholder="Your new email.."> 
    <input type="text" id="name" name="fullname" placeholder="Your new full name..">
    <input type="text" id="address" name="fulladdr" placeholder="Your new full address..">
    <input type="text" id="zip" name="zipcode" placeholder="Your new zip code..">
    <select id="country" name="country">
      <option value="australia">Australia</option>
      <option value="canada">Canada</option>
      <option value="usa">USA</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</div>

function opentab1(evt, tabname) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;



if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 680px)").matches) {

      document.getElementById("main").style.display="none";
      document.getElementById("side").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("edit").style.display="none";

     document.getElementById("actform").style.display="none";


     document.getElementById("profile").style.display="block";
   document.getElementById("profile").style.position="fixed";
   document.getElementById("profile").style.top="400px";
   document.getElementById("profile").style.left="10px";


  /* the viewport is at least 400 pixels wide */
} 

else{

    document.getElementById("profile").style.display="none";
    }

  /* the viewport is less than 400 pixels wide */
    document.getElementById("main").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("side").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("edit").style.display="none";

     document.getElementById("actform").style.display="none";

     document.getElementById("profile").style.display="block";




}

function opentab2(evt, tabname) {
    // Declare all variables
    var i, tabcontent, tablinks;
if (window.matchMedia("(max-width: 680px)").matches) {

    document.getElementById("main").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("side").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("profile").style.display="none";

     document.getElementById("edit").style.display="block";
     document.getElementById("actform").style.position="fixed";
     document.getElementById("actform").style.top="300px";
     document.getElementById("actform").style.left="10px";

}


else{
document.getElementById("edit").style.display="none";
     document.getElementById("actform").style.display="none";

}



     document.getElementById("main").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("profile").style.display="none";
    document.getElementById("side").style.display="none";

     document.getElementById("edit").style.display="block";
     document.getElementById("actform").style.display="block";



}
```

Comment: You never close your table. You're missing `</tbody>` and `</table>`.

Comment: Can you show the javascript code please?

Comment: So, did you try closing the table or have you logged off?

Comment: just a tip - never do inline js or inline css - it's bad practice that leads to hard-to-maintain code

Comment: I guess it wasn't that important. I'm out...

Comment: @MagnusEriksson hey magnus sorry for delay...actually adding tbody and table closing tags work but where do I add it? In the while loop? If i add in while loop the display of table is abnormal ..border missing at second row..Also added JS up

Comment: @MagnusEriksson ok now its working after doing this while( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc( $run_query)){
          echo "<tbody><tr><td>{$row['id']}</td><td>{$row['email']}</td><td>{$row['status']}</td><td>{$row['zip']}</td><td>{$row['name']}</td><td>{$row['password']}</td><td>{$row['address']}</td><td>{$row['country']}</td><td>{$row['expires']}</td></tr></tbody>\n";
        } .  echo '</table>';
Thanks!

Comment: The `</tbody>` should also be after the while loop. Just check the generated output and you will see if it is correct.